# Expo : Cannot load an AV asset from a null playback source

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

Hi I was trying to use Expo-AV but keep getting the warning
`[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Cannot load an AV asset from a null playback source]`

When the sound play function first called it show this warning and dosen't plays but after it when I again recall the function it plays without the warning.

```js
const [sound, setSound] = useState();
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

async function playSound() {
    console.log("Loading Sound");
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      { uri },
      { shouldPlay: true }
    );
    setSound(sound);
    console.log("Playing Sound");
    setIsPlaying(true);
    await sound.playAsync();
    sound._onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status) => {
      if (status.didJustFinish) {
        setIsPlaying(false);
        console.log("Finished");
      }
    };
  }
```

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound()}> 
  <Text>Play</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Is there anyway to play after loading properly.

Comment: Check if `uri` is `undefined` or not?

Comment: No url is not undefined :(

Comment: I'm also running into this same issue. Following, interestingly, the video also started breaking as well.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Try it out
Over here I'm playing an audio that was selected by the user with the DocumentPicker library from Expo.

```bash
const prepareToPlay = async (audioPath) => {
    const sound = new Audio.Sound();

    try {
        await sound.loadAsync({
            uri: audioPath.file,
            shouldPlay: true,
        });
        await sound.playAsync();
        // Your sound is playing!

        // Dont forget to unload the sound from memory
        // when you are done using the Sound object
        // await sound.unloadAsync();
    } catch (error) {
        // An error occurred!
        console.error('AUDIO PLAY: ', error);
    }
};

const audioToBePlayed =  {
    "file": "file:///Users/crosbyroads/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/54AE93CW-1667-491F-A9C7-B457N8BC1207/data/Containers/Data/Application/5C442DA1-4EEA-4F24-93C2-38131484EE9E/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%crosbyroads%252FPlaySounds/DocumentPicker/EE3ECE8E-DFDC-46C9-8B68-4A8E0A8BB808.wav",
    "name": "assets_audio_OS_SB_160_Dm_Cream_Stack_1.wav",
    "size": 3180496,
    "type": "audio/wav",
  }

...

<Button onPress={() => prepareToPlay(audioToBePlayed)} title="Play"></Button>
```